# Accessing Spring Controller Name from View

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

With Spring, how can i retrieve the following Controller attributes in the view?

- Controller name
- Controller's @RequestMapping URI
- Action method name
- Action method's @RequestMapping URI

One approach which i have tried is by creating a subclass of HandlerInterceptorAdapter and overriding postHandle. I register my subclass as an mvc:interceptor for a list of given paths - which is clunky to maintain but was the only way to avoid my interceptor being called for ResourceHandler requests (which i don't want). In my postHandle i can easily add the 2 name attributes, but not the URIs...

1. Parsing from the HttpRequest object requires constraints on all Controller RequestMappings. I.e. i must always map /Controller/Action or equiv scheme. Quite limiting.
2. Creating an ApplicationContext and querying that with the requestURI is too long-winded.

I am thinking about dropping the HandlerInterceptorAdapter and instead defining a BaseController for all my controllers to extend.

I wanted to ask before i do this, is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't stated why you need to do this (it sometimes helps to include your motivation, as others can suggest alternative approaches).

But I'm guessing that the Spring 3.1 features loosely termed "end point documentation" may do what you are asking... See `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` in the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-31-vs-30) which doesn't provide a lot of detail, so this example project is the best place to see it in action:

- [Spring MVC 3.1 Demo App](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-31-demo)
- [example controller](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-31-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc31/endpointdoc/EndpointDocumentationController.java)
- [example JSP page](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-31-demo/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/endpointdoc.jsp)

Comment: I need certain attributes to be available in the view (using JSP / JSTL currently) for decision making on things like "should this navigation bar element be highlighted?" and "what should the Breadcrumbs view contain?".

Comment: Why not use `${pageContext.request.requestURI}` or one of the other request object attributes? Needing the controller name seems superflous, you should be able to achieve it with just the request URI surely?

Comment: I can't see a way of figuring out what to render for a breadcrumb view with out resorting to some fairly involved URI parsing logic in my JSPs. Take /assets/getbyid/12345 vs /assets/listbydate/2012/08/15 how would I convert just those 2 URLs to breadcrumbs without hard coding knowledge of how URLs are interpreted in my view layer? It seems to me the better approach would be to provide the knowledge at the request scope level rather than parsing out at render time.

Comment: A taglib would be one approach - then you contain the logic in one place inside Java code (not JSP/JSTL). Easy to unit test as well. Your example didn't mention what the breadcrumb for those URIs needs to be so I can only guess what the logic required is... one contains "id", the other contains "list"???